# Are other apps allowed to see Firebase Users photoUri in any way?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Weird question but I want to store something private on users's photoUri which is (I thought) tricky. And I don't want other apps to be able to see this information.

Is this a secure way?

More explanation: I want to store RSAPrivateKey there in a string -> uri form.

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("SOME_PRIVATE_INFORMATION"))
        .build();
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish here.  Your post has two questions.  I suggest narrowing it down to a single question with an explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm just asking when I do that, can other apps see it or not? So secure or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client app code can't reach directly into a Firebase user profile.  Any information you store in there is "secure" in that respect, as long as you don't surface it anywhere else in your app, such as your database, or through some API call to a backend that you control that uses the Firebase Admin SDK to read and write profile data.